# Как разбить текст на строки в django?

Tags: django

Я получаю текст из бд. В шаблон мне надо выводить список, каждый элемент которого представляет из себя отдельную строку(в смысле текст должен разбиваться по '\n'). Вопрос как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, что бы переносились строки при генерации из шаблона так же как и были введены в textarea?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549947/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0):

В папке **templatetags** создать файлы **new_tags.py** и **__init__.py**. Содержимое **new_tags.py**:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, splitter):
    return value.split(splitter)
```

В шаблоне:

```
{% load new_tags %}
<ul>
{% for item in text|split:"\n" %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Более подробно про свои тэги шаблона: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/